# How to get apply functions to have side effects?

Tags: r, apply, side-effects

I would like the function that gets called by an apply function to have side effects in the global scope, i.e. to affect variables in the global scope. This doesn't work as you can see:

```
library(zoo)
test=1
rollapply(1:10, width=2, function(x) test=test+1)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
test
# 1
```

I would like test to get incremented every time `function(x)` gets called unfortunately test is still `1` after `rollapply` was executed. Is it possible to get around that?

Comment: Isn't `NULL + 1` giving `numeric(0)`?

Comment: You can do this using the '<<-' assignment parameter, but it's not considered good practice.

Comment: `assign` takes environment arguments, `<<-` with search through all the parent.frames until it reaches the global, in which it will assign a new value if it found nothing.

Comment: @Pascal right i edited, still doesn't work tho

Comment: @Heroka very nice, why is it bad ?

Comment: it's not bad, it's essential in recursive functions for example

Comment: @bunk it's possible to write a recursive function without using '<<-'.

Comment: yes, but you will be copying the object on every call, which is terrible.  But I know what you mean, `<<-` can obviously (usually) have unintended effects.

Comment: @Wicelo I'll be more nuanced. It's not necessarily bad, but you need to know what you're doing. Personally, I can be a bit controlling about my variables, so if I overwrite them I want to do it myself.

Comment: Usually, if you have to ask how to do this, you are not aware of better ways to achieve your actual objective. That's why the standard answer to this question is that you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @Roland it's true that I'm having hard time to solve a problem because of the awkwardness of apply functions.

Comment: @wicelo if you describe what exactly you want to solve, we might be able to provide more to-the-point advice on wheter using `<<-` is appropriate, and what valid alternatives might be.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, R does not support changing variables out side of the scope of a function. The reason for this is to decrease the interconnectedness of your code. This is a good thing, as it makes it easier to reason what a particular piece of code is doing, without having to take into account all the context around it. Especially in larger programs, this can create very hard to fix bugs.

However, using the `<<-` operator you overwrite this behavior:

```
a = 1
spam = function() {
    a <<- a + 1
}
spam()
a
[1] 2
```

However, this if normally not needed and discouraged.

Normally, functions do not keep state, i.e. once a function is done all information inside the function is discarded. Have a look at [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) to get functions that do keep state, which might solve your issue (which you did not state).